# Django manage.py syncdb not creating models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django project, I have configured the database settings in settings.py, and I have created database models in a file.  What else do I need to do for `manage.py syncdb` to create the corresponding tables in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two more steps.  First, database models must be in a file called `models.py`.  Other files aren't recognized by django for database models.  Second, you need to add an entry to `INSTALLED_APPS` inside `settings.py` for the module containing this models.py.  So, if you have in your project `somedir/models.py`, you need to have in your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #...
    "somedir",
)
```